# kendo ui mvc editor "greater than or equal" iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, itext

I have upgraded my MVC 4 application to MVC 5, and from Telerik MVC Editor 2011.2.712 to Kendo UI MVC Editor 2018.2.260.  I am using iTextSharp 5.5.2 to generate PDF.

When I enter ≤7 in the old program, it is saved as

```
<p></p>≤7<p></p>
```

Generates the correct PDF output ≤7

However in Kendo, it is saved as

```
<p>&le;7<br /></p>
```

The  `≤` is missing in the PDF!

Comment: Have you considered expanding that entity before feeding the html to itext?

Comment: I did using if (recomm.Contains("&le;")){recomm = recomm.Replace("&le;", "≤");}; still does not show in the PDF

Comment: Then there are other relevant differences. Other fonts?

Comment: I am using same font in both applications:
 BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontpath + "ARIALUNI.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

Comment: Have you tried using `&#8804;` instead?

Comment: Thanks; unfortunately, didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200027/discussion-between-hncl-and-mkl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues: 
First, I was using iTextSharp 5.3.0 in the new application, I changed it to 5.2.0.
Second, Kendo UI Editor output  `≤ as &le;` I had to change it using:

```
 if (recomm.Contains("&le;")){
recomm = recomm.Replace("&le;", "≤");
};
```